# How to pass selected value from one form to another without storing

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to send selected value from one form to another, then take that value as an int and use in a loop

VIEW:

```
def Base(request, *args, **kwargs):
    template_name = 'Base.html'
    odd = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
    form = Base_form(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            no_of = request.POST.get('odd')
            return HttpResponseRedirect("loopthru.html")

    return render(request, template_name, {'odd': odd})
def loopthru(request, *args, **kwargs):
    template_name = 'loopthru.html'
    print(request.POST.get('odd'))
    form = P2_NexusLeafPair_form(request.POST or None)
...
```

How to pass the value from one form to another and then ran the function `loopthru` automatic and render the html data.

Comment: Use a form wizard https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

Comment: thanks, its seem way complicated, just to pass the single value to a different form, is there any other way beside `wizard form`.. thanks once again